# Outputting a decimal value as two little-endian hex bytes to a file

Tags: linux, bash, data-conversion

I have a need for a bash command that does the following:

> Write a new file in which the two first bytes contain the raw hex bytes (not ASCII) of a value (start address in this case). I.e., 49152 should be written to the file as `00 c0`.

I tried several combinations of `printf`, `xxd`, `fold`, `tac/cat` etc.

```
printf "%X\\n" 49152 | fold -w2|tac|tr -d "\n"
```

This presents me with the ASCII representation of what I need, not the raw HEX bytes.

Comment: This is about creating a binary file that starts with the start address of the code that follows. So $C000 would be the start address of the program that comes after the 2 first bytes.

Comment: hexdump would only work on files, this is supposed to be used in a command line

Comment: Did you try this: `{ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null; printf $'\xc0'; } >yourfile.bin` ?

Comment: The thing is, the $c000 (49152) is a variable, not a fixed value.

Comment: Bash is really a poor choice for handling binary data. You could do arithmetics to transform an integer into your endian two bytes, and offload to `dd` for null bytes that bash can not produce. What the point? Use Python or even Perl or any other language that can deal with binary data.

Comment: I guess i'd better start learning Python then...
Isn't there a simple way to write the hex value of the printf statement above to a file, instead of its ASCII representation?  (Convert ASCII to binary data)

Comment: [Write hexadecimal values to binary file with Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/377452), [How to write a binary file using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5582778/608639), [How to write binary data in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43214001/608639), [How to write integer to binary file using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9955020/608639), [How to create binary file using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8521240/608639), etc.

Comment: `printf`, `xxd`, `tac`, `fold` and `tr` are not `bash`, so if they are ok, presumably so are `Perl` and `Python` which would, IMHO, be better (less clumsy) choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
value=49152
printf "\x$(printf %x $(($value-$value/256*256)))\x$(printf %x $(($value/256)))" > file.txt

hexdump -C file.txt
```

Output:

```
00000000  00 c0                                             |..|
00000002
```